# Error C++ Cocos2D Sprite::create()

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, assertion

I'm developing a game with Cocos2Dx and I'm in trouble with something as easy as opening an image for Sprite.

```
auto background = Sprite::create("images/MainMenuScreen/Background.png");
```

The error is:

```
"Debug Assertion Failed!

Program:
...mbsCocos\TheCatacombs\proj.win32\Debug.win32\TheCatacombs.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0dat.c
Line: 1035

Expression: _wpgmptr != NULL

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts."
```

The error doesn't appear on Visual Studio, but on the game itself when it starts.

The problem is that line, if I comment it the error disappears.

The path is right and the file exists, I've already checked that, furthermore the error doesn't talk about the image nor the path.

Any idea?

Comment: that error doesn't look related to that line. what's happening on the line above this sprite creation?

Comment: This is what happens above "Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();". But I don't think this is the problem. And if I comment the line in the post, the error disappears.

Comment: Did you try running the program in release mode ? Also, an error in your code could be manifesting long after its origin. So I would maybe check all the code related to sprites

Comment: Can you include more code then? This is weird.

Comment: Blake_Lead: yes I tried running in release mode, error samely. TankorSmash: what other code?

Comment: Did you found the answer ? i facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Typically errors generated by the heap internals of the c++ runtime are indicative of a problem that happened elsewhere in the program and are manifesting now that you are trying to allocate more memory.

The Microsoft C/C++ runtime provides debug methods to validate the heap and they can be quite helpful to isolate the source of a heap corruption by allowing you to explicitly test the state of the heap at crucial points in your application.

See [_CrtValidateHeap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e73x0s4b.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the folder for search that image? 
Try to:
in AppDelegate.cpp in function applicationDidFinishLaunching() add this line:

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("images");
```

If the images folder in on Resources folder, or try

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("images/MainMenuScreen");
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tza1y5f7.aspx), I found out that `_wpgmptr` contains the full path of the executable file, but it must be used with `wmain()` instead of `main()`.

My project was using `tWinMain()`. When I changed to wmain(), the problem disappeared. This is a quick fix, because the "hello world" project uses `tWinMain()` and runs normally.

If someone knows why this fix works, please, let us know!